# How to set the password for Ldap user account?

Tags: active-directory, ldif

I am using this in ldif file to set the password.

```
dn:cn=krisv,ou=People,dc=jbpm,dc=org
changetype:modify
replace:unicodePwd
unicodePwd:Krisv
-
```

This is the log

```
Connecting to "localhost:389"
Logging in as current user using SSPI
Importing directory from file "MS-Sample.LDF"

Loading entries
1: cn=krisv,ou=People,dc=jbpm,dc=org
Entry DN: cn=krisv,ou=People,dc=jbpm,dc=org
changetype: modify
Attribute 0) unicodePwd:IgA3ACQANQBNAHMAIwA0AEQAaQBHACIA

Add error on entry starting on line 2: Constraint Violation
The server side error is: 0x52c Unable to update the password. The value provided for    the new password contains values that are not allowed in passwords.

The extended server error is:
0000052C: AtrErr: DSID-033805E9, #1:
0: 0000052C: DSID-033805E9, problem 1005 (CONSTRAINT_ATT_TYPE), data 0, Att 9005a    (unicodePwd)
0 entries modified successfully.
An error has occurred in the program
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Apache Directory Studio to manage your LDAP directory. It should help avoiding that sort of problem.

Comment: At this time, 7 years after this answer, Apache still has not documented how to change user passwords in Directory Studio. The documentation page still just says "TODO..."

https://directory.apache.org/apacheds/kerberos-ug/3.3-change-password.html

If anyone has more useful doc than that (almost anything would be), please post it!

Answer (score -1):

Using [Apache Directory Studio](https://nightlies.apache.org/directory/studio/2.0.0.v20210717-M17/userguide/ldap_browser/index.html):

1. Open Directory Studio and connect to your repository.
2. Search/navigate to the user you want to modify.
3. To **add** a password, click the `New Attribute` button or menu `LDAP > New Attribute` (or `SHIFT-CMD-+`).
4. Enter Attribute type `userPassword` then click Next if you want to enter optional language tags, otherwise click Finish.
5. Password Editor opens. Enter and Confirm the new password, and select your hash method (don't leave it at the default `plaintext`!) then click OK.

You should now see a `userPassword` attribute in the list of user attributes.

If you want to change a password attached to an entity, locate the entity in Directory Studio, right-click and select `Extended Operations > Password Modify`. Or, locate the `userPassword` attribute for the entity and double-click it, or select and press `F7`. The Password Editor will be invoked and you can enter previous/new passwords. Note that modifying the password will require authentication using the bind DN.

Comment: This only works for the plaintext `userPassword` attribute. As the OP describes, they are trying to modify `unicodePwd` which is a different beast entirely.

Comment: The dialog box for editing the Password allows for selection of hash method. It is not limited only to plaintext password. OP did not state specifically that unicode password was required; only that it was in the LDIF file. Question was "How to set the password for Ldap user account?"

Comment: Andy: except that in the LDIF code sample the attribute `unicodePwd` is being altered.

Answer (score -2):

In Apache Directory Studio, you can change a user password by double clicking the **userPassword** attribute description. This will open the Password Editor, where you can verify the current password or enter a new password.